# No Activity found to handle Intent act=android.intent.action.VIEW when trying to play an audio file

Tags: java, android, android-intent

It works for 3-4 files, but after that it just starts crashing.

Here's the code -

```
fileName = list.get(position);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file1 = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file1), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Log -

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appname/files/DCIM/.foldername/+33535_25.mp3 typ=audio/* }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1602)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4340)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4312)
at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1075)
at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
```

Comment: Post the crash error from logcat.

Comment: @Simas, it has been added.

Comment: Have you tried adding `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` ?

Comment: is the path to that file correct? There is a `+` in the name of the mp3 file?

Comment: @SebastianWalla, there can't be? So that must be causing it. It's actually a phone number that I've cut out.

Comment: @SebastianWalla, seems like that's not what's causing it.

Comment: could you update your stacktrace? I saw the `+` here `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appname/files/DCIM/.foldername/+33535_25.mp3 typ=audio/* }`

Comment: I haven't changed the stacktrace. That part of the line is still there, and the `+` isn't the problem, seems like.

Comment: Sidenote: Why would you use [DCIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system#Directory_and_file_structure) for audio files?